# Renaming and removing Tags from XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, rename

I am trying to rename and remove of some fields in single XSLT code, but somehow rename option is not working.
Below is my XML data with SOAP tags and would need to remove the tags and replace them with a required namespace. Paralally I should change the name of an XML tag since the particular name of source xml should be changed.

thank you

My Source XML

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <ParentTag>
                <tagRequest>
                    <Data1>FirstName</Data1>
                    <Data2>LastName</Data2>
                    <Value1>50</Value1>
                    <BooleanValue1>false</BooleanValue1>
                    <Address>
                        <StreetName>0000000</StreetName>
                        <Street-No>00000000000000</Street-No>
                    </Address>
                </tagRequest>
            </ParentTag>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Target Output XML should be :

```
    <ns0:MainNode xmlns:ns0="http://test/system">
    <ParentTag>
        <tagRequest>
            <Data1>FirstName</Data1>
            <Data2>LastName</Data2>
            <Value1>50</Value1>
            <BooleanValue1>false</BooleanValue1>
            <Address>
                <StreetName>0000000</StreetName>
                <StreetNo>00000000000000</StreetNo>
            </Address>
        </tagRequest>
    </ParentTag>
    </ns0:MainNode>
```

Below is the XSLT that I have tried :

```
        <?xml version='1.0' ?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                                      xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                                      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

            <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
            <xsl:template match="/">
                <ns0:MainNode xmlns:ns0="http://test/system">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*" />
                </ns0:MainNode>
            </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template match="Street-No">
                <xsl:element name= "StreetNo">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:template>

        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `xsl:copy-of` to `xsl:apply-templates` and add the *identity template*. After these changes the `Street-No` template will match. `xsl:copy-of` really only copies an element-tree without *applying* templates on the tree. This has to be done with `xsl:apply-templates` which uses the *identity template* to copy all nodes that are not matched by a more specific template.

I also changed the matching expression to be namespace-independent like `*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*` so that  the `soap` namespace is not used at all.

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                              xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ns0:MainNode xmlns:ns0="http://test/system">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*" />
        </ns0:MainNode>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Street-No">
        <xsl:element name= "StreetNo">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:MainNode xmlns:ns0="http://test/system">
  <ParentTag>
        <tagRequest>
            <Data1>FirstName</Data1>
            <Data2>LastName</Data2>
            <Value1>50</Value1>
            <BooleanValue1>false</BooleanValue1>
            <Address>
                <StreetName>0000000</StreetName>
                <StreetNo>00000000000000</StreetNo>
            </Address>
        </tagRequest>
    </ParentTag>
</ns0:MainNode>
```

Comment: Thank  you. I am getting the desired output. But it has the namespace appending as xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/". Is there a way that this can also be suppressed?

Comment: @Ven: Yes. Is it possible that you didn't copy the whole stylesheet? Because replacing your XPath `soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*` with `*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*` and removing the `xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` from the `xsl:stylesheet` element was intentionally for that case.